# Can I add a Mini Pci-e Ssd in my laptop's slot (where Wifi is now)?

Tags: ssd, pci-express, minipci

I have an HP-tx1000. It has 4 Gb ram now but its slow HDD doesn't let me do serious stuff.

I wonder If I can put a [mini pci-e ssd](http://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_nkw=mini%20pci-e%20ssd&_sacat=0&_odkw=mini%20pci-e&_osacat=0&_trksid=p3286.c0.m270.l1313) in place of the WLAN card.

Will this work on Win7 x64?

Comment: That's the first I've ever seen a pcie ssd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [PCI Express - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Mini_PCI_Express_.26_mSATA):

> Some notebooks (notably the Asus Eee PC, the MacBook Air, and the Dell mini9 and mini10) use a variant of the PCI Express Mini Card as an SSD. This variant uses the reserved and several non-reserved pins to implement SATA and IDE interface passthrough, keeping only USB, ground lines, and sometimes the core PCIe 1x bus intact. **This makes the miniPCIe flash and solid state drives sold for netbooks largely incompatible with true PCI Express Mini implementations.**

I guess that means that it probably will not work.